# What are the ranges of CO2 levels for inner cities and should CO2 be added to the air quality index?

Tags: climate-change, air-quality, urban-climate

I have a indoor $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ monitor and putting it on my balcony it indicates values of 1400-2200 ppm for different days ? Is this even possible and what are the ranges of $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ levels for the outside air of larger inner cities ?

Also should $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ be added to the list of gasses measured by the air quality index ? I know it doesn't accurately measure the source that generates the $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$, but at least people should have a general idea of the levels of $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ in different areas so they can better pick a cleaner place to live in.

Comment: it makes no sense to include this in the air quality index,had it been 10times higher then it had been a good idea to include it.

Comment: [A chart here](https://medium.com/@joeljean/im-living-in-a-carbon-bubble-literally-b7c391e8ab6) says typical city center  ~500 ppm.